# Weapon Target Assignment Problem + Time Windows

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

So I am very familiar with the WTAP it the static case. What I am wondering, is there a formulation that has "time windows" as well? Let's say you have some weapons and some targets, you know the probabilities of kill and the probabilities of that target avoiding. On top of that you also know available time windows in which each weapon can access each target.

Is this a simultaneous problem, or should it be a WTPA, followed by a scheduling problem?